# How to correctly do a droppable on sortables?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Take the example code snippet below:

If you click and drag `Item 1` over `Item 2` (or one of the other items) it will turn gray as to indicate it is droppable.

Drag it further so sortable kicks in and `Item 2` moves up to `Item 1's` previous location - if you notice now the droppable location for `Item 2` is still located at `Item 2's` original location and not moved with `Item 2` to its now current location where `Item 1` was previously located.

It somehow seems like, at least in its default states, a droppable on a sortable is not possible. So how do I correctly do a droppable on sortables?

```js
$("#sortable").sortable({ cursor: "move" });
$("#sortable > li").droppable({ hoverClass: "hover" });
```

```css
.pointer { cursor: pointer; }
.hover { background: #cccccc; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>sortable demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<ul id="sortable" class="pointer">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an undocumented option for the sortable, `refreshPositions: true`, did just what I needed.